# show hide button based on the score achieved

Tags: php, html, mysql

what I would like to achieve:
show the text instead of the button if the sum of the points does not correspond to the calculation of the points.

Tables:
Table: points calculation
in this table the user enters the value of the single point example the value entered is 10.

Table: Points
the points entered during the purchase of an example product are saved inside
20 points

I have this select

```
<?php
require_once("../config/config.php");
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT punti.id_cliente, SUM(punti.punti) as punti, calcolo_punti.id_calcolo, calcolo_punti.calcolo as calcolo FROM punti INNER JOIN calcolo_punti
WHERE punti.id_cliente=='" . $_GET["id_cliente"] . "' GROUP BY id_cliente");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
if ($row['punti'] >= ($row['calcolo'])) {
include('scala.php');
} else {
echo "<div style='font-size:16px;text-align:center;'>
Non ci sono abbastanza punti per elaborare i buoni sconto.</div>";}
?>
```

1- SUM(punti.punti) as punti
this sum the points present inside in this case like the example above is 20 points

2- calcolo_punti.calcolo as calcolo
the value 10 is present in the database as in the example above

in this case if ($row['punti'] >= ($row['calcolo'])) Punti is greater than or equal to Calcolo must show the button

if instead ($row['punti'] >= ($row['calcolo'])) is less the button must be hidden and show the text There are not enough points to process the discount coupons

i tried in this

```
if ($row['punti'] >= ($row['calcolo'])) {
include('scala.php');
} else {
echo "<div style='font-size:16px;text-align:center;'>
Non ci sono abbastanza punti per elaborare i buoni sconto.</div>";}
```

way but it doesn't work, maybe something wrong in the select?

thanks for your help

Comment: ok, I am not going to preach to you that your code is open to SQL Injection but have you tried the `select` query directly to you DB? does it return any value? else, you can `var_dump($row)` to check if any data exist before doing the comparison

Comment: thanks for the reply, i tried on the db and the values are blank

Comment: if the database fields in the POINTS section are empty, if the fields in the database in the POINTS section are full it works

Comment: You just answered ur own question. Check if it contain any data first before doing the point comparison. The comparison will definitely fail if one of the 2 points empty